# AnimatorUpdateListener is called on multiple thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-animation

Is AnimatorUpdateListener supposed to be called on UI thread only? I have a value animation that updates the view color. So the code looks like:

```
class CustomView extends View {


    public void startAnimation() {

         ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), 
             mStartColor, mEndColor);
         animation.setDuration(500L);
         animation = new CustomAnimatorUpdateListener(this);
    }

   private static class CustomAnimatorUpdateListener implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

    private final WeakReference<View> mHostViewRef;

    CustomAnimatorUpdateListener(@NonNull final View hostView) {
        mHostViewRef = new WeakReference<>(hostView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        if (mHostViewRef.get() != null) {
            mHostViewRef.get().setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue()); // Crash on this line
        }
    }
}
```

The crash is

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
```

Seems like one thread is getting non-null in the if check mHostViewRef.get() != null, and another thread is doing the if block, and it returns null and then app crashes.

I'd like to know, is this AnimatorUpdateListener always called on UI thread? or could be on background thread?

Comment: Well, regularly, you normally **don't** handle views in non-UI threads...

Comment: @chisko do you mean that the onAnimationUpdate is called on background thread?

Comment: *"Seems like one thread is getting non-null in the if check mHostViewRef.get() != null"* why are you so sure of that?

Comment: I am not so sure, thats why I said "Seems like,,,"

Comment: the exception appears to tell that your `hMostViewRef` is getting disposed, why don't you use a regular class member instead?

Comment: you appear to be so sure of what I ask because your question appears to indicate that you are doing multithreading *and* know what you are doing